# How to lookup an index in Yahoo's stock API

Tags: yahoo-finance

I'm using Yahoo's stock API to get stock quotes, [as described here](http://www.gummy-stuff.org/Yahoo-data.htm).

Basically, I just assemble a link like this:

> http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=DOW+MSFT+AAPL+GOOG&f=snl1

which'll give me a list of the current price for those stocks (DOW, MSFT, AAPL, GOOG).

---

All's nice and dandy, but I'd also like to get the info for the NASDAQ and S&P 500 Indices, but I have no idea what to use as the symbol for those.

I tried all of these:

> NASDAQ
>
> INDEXNASDAQ
>
> INDEXNASDAQ:.IXIC
>
> INDEXNASDAQ.IXIC
>
> IXIC

to no avail.

It seems like I have the whole idea flawed (I don't really know much about finance).

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the same symbols you see on the corresponding Yahoo finance page.

Nasdaq = ^IXIC

S&P = ^GSPC

Dow = ^DJI

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize that the `^` was part of the symbol. Is that to denote that it's an index?

Comment: Seems that it is not available actually: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679870/yahoo-finance-csv-file-will-not-return-dow-jones-dji

Comment: would you know how I could look up the dow in [Google's API](http://www.google.com/ig/api?stock=goog)?

Comment: @MegaHit Dow works as well - http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/%5EDJI/quotes