# Can't get all data from Yahoo finance API

Tags: python, api, pandas, yahoo-finance

I'm using python pandas in order to get stock/index prices from yahoo finance. I use the 
`web.DataReader([list of stocks], 'yahoo', start, end)`

Many of these stocks are working fine. However, one doesn't. My questions is: How can I manage to successfully gather all of them?

The one called ^DJCI is the one that doesn't work. It is available on the website of yahoo and it has data. I can't even get it individually by doing the following:

```
web.DataReader('^DJCI', 'yahoo', start, end)
```

I get the following error:

```
IOError: after 3 tries, Yahoo! did not return a 200 for url 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=^DJCI&a=0&b=1&c=2015&d=0&e=9&f=2016&g=d&ignore=.csv'
```

Comment: Load that URL in a browser. You have provided an invalid URL.

Comment: Keep it simple! Try `web.DataReader('DJCI', 'yahoo', start, end)`

Comment: DJCI and ^DJCI are unfortunately different stocks. DJCI works but it doesn't solve my problem. Here is the link to ^DJCI: http://finance.yahoo.com/q;_ylt=AoLanflTrlWqZkhs7gTJUBNzAcAF?uhb=uhb2&fr=uh3_finance_vert_gs_ctrl2_e&type=2button&s=%5EDJCI

Comment: Or this link: https://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=^DJCI

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for `%5EDJCI`. That is equivalent to `^DJCI`. The reason `^DJCI` didn't work might because `^` is not a normal character and you need to <sup>1</sup>escape it.


1: I don't know the proper term for converting ^ to %5E.

### EDIT 1

See [Yahoo! Finance CSV file will not return Dow Jones (^DJI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679870/yahoo-finance-csv-file-will-not-return-dow-jones-dji?lq=1)

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work either. It failed in the same manner.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679870/yahoo-finance-csv-file-will-not-return-dow-jones-dji?lq=1.

Comment: The term is "URL encoding"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the special character in `^DJCI` the problem is the availability of historical data of that index, if you check [Historical Prices](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=%5EDJCI%20Historical%20Prices) this message is displayed:

```
Historical quote data is unavailable for the specified date range.
```

I search other source like Quandl, with no luck. But according [this article](http://www.indexologyblog.com/2014/07/01/dow-jones-commodity-index-wins-independence/), you could have good correlation with "iShares S&P GSCI Commodity-Indexed Trust (GSG)", if you find a free source of `^DJCI` please let me know.
By this time a good alternative is to use `GSG`

```
web.DataReader('GSG', 'yahoo', start, end)
```